# WP_Query & shortcode : Return 3 articles from a category WordPress

Tags: wp-query, functions, shortcode

I would like to display the last 3 articles of category 'camping-camping' with a shortcode but the function does not seem valid, an idea ?

```
function derniers_articles_camping() {

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
  'category_name' => 'location-camping-var',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
)); 


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

$contenu = '
```

```
<div class="effect-jazz">'.the_post_thumbnail();.'<div class="jazz-try">
        <div class="h3"><a href="'.the_permalink();.'">'.the_title();.'</a></div>
        <p>'the_resume(60);.'</p>
    </div>          
</div>
```

```
 ';

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();

return $contenu;

endif;

} 

add_shortcode('camping', 'derniers_articles_camping');
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `$contenu` variable.

Try:

```
$contenu .= '<div class="effect-jazz">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'<div class="jazz-try">
    <div class="h3"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></div>
    <p>'.get_the_resume(60).'</p><!-- THIS FUNCTION NEEDS TO BE CREATED -->
</div>
</div>';
```

Do not use `;` trailers when using inline php, ex `<a href="'.get_permalink().'">`.

Use the appropriate return functions:

- [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/)
- [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)
- [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/)
- Create a `return` version of `the_resume()` function

Do use the correct operator `.=` when you wish to append to a variable, rather than overwrite it with each loop iteration.

Do not line break after `$variable .= '`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution :

```
ob_start();

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
 'category_name' => 'location-camping-var',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
)); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ){

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-md-4">

        <div class="grid">

            <div class="effect-jazz">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('child-thumb'); ?>
                <div class="jazz-try">
                    <div class="h3"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                </div>          
            </div>

        </div>

        </div>

        <?php

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    $laboucle = ob_get_clean();
    return $laboucle;

    }
```